# How to open couchbaselite (.cblite2) file

Tags: couchbase-lite

I am working on Couchbaselite phonegap based app.I need to see data getting inserted in database. To view this data I downloaded Couchbase Lite Viewer (v 0.61) but with that it is not opening ,giving following error popup[image].
Any other software available to view Couchbase lite data?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you compile Couchbase Lite Viewer yourself, it will support viewing this kind of database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks borrrden 2 ,it is working...
I followed exact steps given on this link https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchbaseLiteViewer and working for me now.

Comment: its for mac, is there any for windows?